# xamarin.forms - Cant add anything to launchscreen

Tags: xamarin.forms

I appear to missing something as I am not able to add image to my launchscreen. There was a list of elements I could pick, but now its no longer there.

[image]

Comment: Apparently they are called controls and this is starting to get annoying

Comment: you appear to be looking at the properties panel for the file, not the actual editor

Comment: How do I look at the actual editor?

Comment: usually you double-click on the file, like you would with any other file in VS

Comment: Yea the controls are still not there....I need to add an image to launchscreen, but cant

Comment: @user979331,According to your description, whether you want to add image in launchscreen in Xamarin.forms for ios? If yes, there is one msdn article about this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=windows